# Magento Blocks CMS Home Site right sidebar

Tags: cms-block

i want to create my own CMS Home site with 2 columns with right sidebar. I added a block under "CMS -> Static Block" with an identifier. I added under CMS -> Pages -> home my own XML Layout:

```
<reference name="right"><block type="cms/block" name="right.permanent.callout"><action method="setBlockId"><block_id>artmotor_news</block_id></action></block></reference>
```

The block is shown, but how can i add another block under this block.?

andre

Answer (score 1):

```
<reference name="right">
    <block type="cms/block" name="right.permanent.callout">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>artmotor_news</block_id></action>
    </block>
    <block type="cms/block" name="other.name.here" after="right.permanent.callout">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_alias_here</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="right">
   <block type="cms/block" name="right.permanent.callout2" after="right.permanent.callout">
         <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>artmotor_news</block_id></action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

set your data as per you need just add after="block of name".